# Are multiple sprouted potato eyes okay?

Tags: containers, seedlings, potatoes

[image]
So recently I saw that my 3 potato's sprouted in my 7 gallon pot. However each potato had 2 or 3 eyes and all of them came to. Could they be overcrowded and if so, do I need to prune and leave only single plants behind.